# Quantization of torch tensors to reduce storage size

Tags: memory-management, pytorch, torch, quantization, quantize

I have a number (`N`) of vectors of size `192 x 1` currently stored as torch tensors. Each element in the tensor are float numbers. These `N`vectors are used to be compared against a reference vector by its' similarity.

Now, `N` can be very large and hence these vectors start to actually consume some memory after a while. Therefore, I'd like to try some quantization methods to potentially reduce the memory needed to store them. For instance, by storing them with fewer bits (at the cost of lower precision).

Is there a convenient way to do this while preserving the comparability between a reference vector and the `N` stored vectors?

I've tried using;

```
q_vec = torch.quantize_per_tensor_dynamic(vec, torch.quint8, True)
```

But using `getsizeof(x)` the size is still the same as before quantization. Obviously, I'm probably missing something or misunderstanding the concept here. Any nudge in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using sys.getsizeof(q_vec), as it will return a constant value for tensors, you should use:

q_vec.element_size() * q_vec.nelement()

And then measure the before vs after sizes.